# How do I check what user agent curl is using?

Tags: curl

I'm attempting using curl to monitor the contents of a page served by a remote HTTP server (which I have very little control over), and for some reason the server is returning different results depending on what machine I'm running curl from. I suspect this might be due to a difference in the user agent strings curl is using on each machine.

How do I check (not set) what user agent string curl is sending to the remote server in its HTTP requests?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the [`--verbose`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) option to see all the headers sent by curl, including `User-Agent`:

> A line starting with '>' means "header data" sent by curl

For example:

```bash
$ curl --verbose 'http://www.google.com/'
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: www.google.com
> Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
curl ifconfig.me/ua
```

However the output would be "Curl and your curl version"

for example:

```
curl/7.64.0
```

Comment: This unnecessarily returns an extraneous trailing `⏎` character.

Comment: It returns nothing for me...perhaps its returning an invisible newline character as the previous comment suggests?

Comment: The "return" character works on Windows but not under Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the JSON service https://ifconfig.co:

```
curl ifconfig.co/json -s | grep  "raw_value"
```

It will return the full user-agent string.

Exemple of answer for *curl* version 8.1.2:

> "raw_value": "curl/8.1.2"